# Variables in a string C++

Tags: c++

> I have the next c++ program where I have included the iostream and string libraries :

```
int main() {
 int _number = 3;
 std::string caracters = "the value of _number is: $_number$"; 


 return 0;
}
```

> How can I replace $_number$ with the value of _number (3)?

Comment: C++ is not PHP...

Comment: `std::string caracters = "the value of _number is: " + std::to_string(_number);`

Answer (score 2):

You do it like this:

```
std::string caracters = "the value of _number is: " + std::to_string(_number);
```

Comment: I want to replace $_number$ with his value when I call a function to evaluate the string.

Comment: There is no general "eval" function that looks at the current scopes' symbols to resolve string fragments. As pointed out above, C++ is not PHP.